# PersonalJourney.settings metadata

Tags: marketing-cloud, metadata

I recently retrieved entire org's metadata, and among other things found one settings metadata named **PersonalJourney.settings**, for which I can find exatly 0 results on Google. Can anyone shed any light on what this setting is actually used for?

The content of the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonalJourneySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <enableExactTargetForSalesforceApps>false</enableExactTargetForSalesforceApps>
</PersonalJourneySettings>
```

Apart from the obvious that it's somehow related to ExactTarget, how would one explain the existance of that setting metadata on one org, and non-existance on another org? Probably some of the features enabled/disabled, but which one?